# with nginx: http to https and only some paths to http with different ports

Tags: redirect, nginx

I want to have all http to https and only some paths to http with different ports:

```
server { 
  listen 80; 
  servername _; 
  return 301 https://$host$requesturi;

  location /bamboo { 
    rewrite ^/bamboo(.*)$ http://mydomainname:8085/$1 last; 
  }

  location /api { 
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ http://mydomainname:8080/$1 last; 
  }

  return 403; 
}
```

the above does not work,
also this does not work:

```
#Redirect paths
server {
listen 443;
server_name _;

  location /bamboo {
    rewrite ^/bamboo(.*)$ http://mydomainname:8085/$1 last;
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ http://mydomainname:8080/$1 last;
  }

  return 403;
}

#Redirect http -> https 
server { 
  listen 80; 
  servername _; 
  return 301 https://$host$requesturi;

  return 403;
}
```

Is there another way maybe of having all http send to https except these 2 paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would route all traffic on the http server by leveraging the declarative nature of nginx. The most specific location will be selected:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /bamboo/ {
        proxy_pass http://mydomainname:8085/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://mydomainname:8080/;
    }
}
```

Note the trailing / in the proxy_pass arguments for ports 8085 and 8080. It will cause the bamboo and api parts to be removed from the URI as described in the [proxy_pass docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).